# Excel 2003 charts not looking right in 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I'm not exactly sure this goes here but I don't know where else to look for help.

I have some Excel files containing charts made with Excel 2003.  When I open the file in Excel 2007 and save it (non 2007) is messes up the charts.  However, when in Excel 2007 and I Save as a .xlsx type the charts don't mess up.

Is there any help for me to be able to not have the charts mess up when simply saving the 2003 file with Excel 2007?

Hope that's confusing.  Thanks.

Comment: I think the short answer is 'No'.  by any chance have you tried saving the files in 2007 format form **from** 2003?

Answer (score 0):

Applying 'the decimal version of time' (as in question below) to your Excel 2003 sheets might help but if only because it has been three years, you can probably tell the long answer is also 'No'.

Excel 2007 charting is in some ways fundamentally different from Excel 2003 and Excel 2010. ([eg SU148886](https://superuser.com/questions/148886/using-a-time-to-set-xy-chart-axis-scaling-like-in-2003)).

The [blog](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2007/12/17/intraday-time-series-charts.aspx) referred to in that question includes a comment

> “BTW, wouldn't it be a better use of the Excel developer team's time to fix date/time interpretation than writing low information content blog postings?”